# Tips for NetBeans to speed up development

Tags: netbeans

i am looking for tips (eg. keyboard shortcuts/features/tips) that you use to speed up development in netbeans.

i mainly develop in

- HTML, CSS, JS (jQuery)
- PHP

so specific to those will be great

Comment: Also worth reading, but is not an exact dupe as that mainly covers NetBeans with the Java language - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628830/netbeans-tips-and-tricks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a question I asked a while ago, concerning code-folding: [Can you set some sort of custom code folding in Netbeans like in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251803/)

I made it in to a macro, so now I press my keycombo and I place code-folds in the blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0):

Upload on save...and use the save shortcut.  much faster than clicking save, then clicking to upload.